# Sending events data using either gtag.js or analytics.js whichever is available in UA integration

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, gtag.js

I am writing an integration to send data to **Google Analytics**. Google analytics now has two version of tracking code.

gtag.js code:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-79XXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());


gtag('config', 'UA-79XXXXXX-X');
</script>
```

And another old one, using analytics.js

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-79XXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Problem:
***I want a reliable way what type of code is present on the website?***
Means, if the UA code is added via `gtag.js` method or `analytics.js` method, as the API for sending events in both is different.

I tried one way is having `window.gtag` variable on the page. But it is not working reliably as **AdWords** code can also be added via `gtag.js` method.
https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/

I have found some instances where **AdWords** code is added via `gtag.js` method but UA code is added via old one (`analytics.js` method)

PS: I, also, followed this link but can't find a method to reliably detect the same. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration